# What is meant by a reaction favours one side?

Tags: equilibrium

I frequently see in textbooks the phrase, a reaction favours the left/right side, but don't know what this means. Does this mean the equilibrium shifts to one side?

Comment: that is exactly what the phrase "favors one side" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the equilibrium shifts as per Le-Chatelier Principle. Le Châtelier's principle states that if a dynamic equilibrium is disturbed by changing the conditions, the position of equilibrium shifts to counteract the change to reestablish an equilibrium. If a chemical reaction is at equilibrium and experiences a change in pressure, temperature, or concentration of products or reactants, the equilibrium shifts in the opposite direction to offset the change.

**Increasing a concentration**

What happens if conditions are altered by increasing the concentration of A?

According to Le Châtelier, the position of equilibrium will move in such a way as to counteract the change.

[image]

**Decreasing a concentration**

In the opposite case in which the concentration of A is decreased, according to Le Châtelier, the position of equilibrium will move so that the concentration of A increases again.

[image]

**Increasing the pressure**

According to Le Châtelier, if the pressure is increased, the position of equilibrium will move so that the pressure is reduced again. The more molecules in the container, the higher the pressure will be. The system can reduce the pressure by reacting in such a way as to produce fewer molecules.

[image]

**Decreasing the pressure**

The equilibrium will move in such a way that the pressure increases again. It can do that by producing more gaseous molecules. In this case, the position of equilibrium will move towards the left-hand side of the reaction.

[image]

*What happens if there are the same number of molecules on both sides of the equilibrium reaction?*

In this case, increasing the pressure has no effect on the position of the equilibrium. Because there are equal numbers of molecules on both sides, the equilibrium cannot move in any way that will reduce the pressure again.

**Increasing the temperature**

If the temperature is increased, then the position of equilibrium will move so that the temperature is reduced again. The position of equilibrium therefore moves to the left.

[image]

**Decreasing the temperature?**

The equilibrium will move in such a way that the temperature increases again.

[image]

**Catalysts**

Adding a catalyst makes absolutely no difference to the position of equilibrium, and Le Châtelier's principle does not apply. This is because a catalyst speeds up the forward and back reaction to the same extent and adding a catalyst does not affect the relative rates of the two reactions, it cannot affect the position of equilibrium.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, so this phrase means to basically which side the equilibrium will move, whether to the left or the right. So find out that we need to see the number of particles atoms or ions. It basically rely on the fact what a question has been asked for particles ions or atoms. Now to see, we need to first see is there more particles on the left hand side or the right hand side. Where there are more particles, equilibrium rely that that hand or side, so the forward or the backward reaction. Now with a catalyst there will be no effect on the rate of equilibrium for e.g. iron.